# How can I generify a Factory with specific entity type?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, refactoring

How can I generify method `getBuilder` to make him depend not on `Object` but on type of `UnitBuilder` or `SourceBuilder`?

```
public class BuilderFactory {
    Object getBuilder (Object entity) throws UnsupportedResourceEntityType {
        if (entity instanceof Source){
            return new SourceBuilder();
        }
        if (entity instanceof Unit){
            return new UnitBuilder();
        }
        throw new UnsupportedResourceEntityType();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any relationship between `SourceBuilder` and `UnitBuilder` ?

Comment: So why don't you just replace `Object` by this common type ? Or better, by an interface implemented by this common class.

Comment: Yes, but I'm going to remove their super class (a parent class).

Comment: I don't want to cast form `Object` to `UnitBuilder` or `SourceBuilder`.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the parent class ?

Comment: Because it redundant. I replace all logic from it into another class. So it's design decision. Let say I don't have any relationship between `SourceBuilder` and `UnitBuilder`.

Comment: But I still need to generify result of `getBuilder` method :)

Comment: If there is no common supertype, it's definitely impossible. Plus, it would be like if your method could return apples, cars or cats : it makes no sense. There has to be some relationship.

Answer (score 0):

It has little sense to be forced to provide an instance of a class just to know its class. You should pass `SourceBuilder.class` or `UnitBuilder.class` as an argument, so your method would be (I'll assume you keep a common supertype for thos two classes and that these classes have a default constructor) :

```
<T extends SuperType> T getBuilder (Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: No! I can't pass anything into getBuilder method except instance on result class.

Comment: In fact I can't also use Reflection API.

Comment: Because I'm looking for another solution. Reflection is something that I can't use in my code. It's a restriction of my mentor. So no Reflection :)

Comment: Seams in Java there is no way to make it easy and clear.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Java, you are rejecting every good way to do it. If your types have no relationship then your whole method is bad design.

Comment: Because you don't have any guarantee on the returned type, because there is no specific semantic to the return object, because it is OOP not using classes.